# Visualize 3D data in Julia

Tags: julia

I know the function:

```
surf(lst1,lst2,lst3)
```

Is there another one that does the same thing but in the 2d graph, similar to the heat map?

Answer (score 0):

Plotting `lst1, lst2` with `zcolor = lst3` using a large marker or a scatter plot would do that.

```
using Plots

x = 0.0:π/20:2π
y = sin.(x)
z = tanh.(x)

plot(x, y, marker = 10, zcolor = z)
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not clear on the type of graph that you want. The closest thing I can think of for a surface plot in 2D would be a contour plot. The `Plots` interface has a `contour()` function, which you can call the same way as the `heatmap()` function (but has, of course, its own special keywords).